# Is the number $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty2^{-n^2}$ rational?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, number-theory, rationality-testing

> Is the number $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty2^{-n^2}$ rational?

I could prove that the series is convergent (as it is bounded above by the geometric series with common ratio $\frac{1}{2}$. But how do I prove that it is rational (or not)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume that the sum is a rational number given by $\frac{p}{q}$ where $p$ and $q$ are coprime. Choose $n$  such that $q < 2^n$. Then we have:

$$\frac{p}{q} - \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2^{k^2}} = \sum_{k \geqslant n+1}\frac{1}{2^{k^2}}$$

But we know that the sum $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2^{k^2}} = \frac{m}{2^{n^2}}$ for some integer $n$. Therefore,

$$\frac{p}{q}- \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2^{k^2}} =\frac{p}{q}- \frac{m}{2^{n^2}} > \frac{1}{2^{n^2}q} > \frac{1}{2^{n^2 + n}}>\frac{1}{2^{(n+1)^2-1}} = \sum_{k \geqslant(n+1)^2}\frac{1}{2^k} > \sum_{k \geqslant n+1}\frac{1}{2^{k^2}},$$

which is a contradiction! Hence the sum is irrational, infact, I believe it is trancendental.

EDIT: Thanks to Robert Israel for pointing out the mathoverflow link which asserts the transcendence of the number.

Link: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55397/is-this-number-already-known-to-be-transcendental-is-there-a-survey-about-up-to

Comment: See [this Math overflow question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/55397/is-this-number-already-known-to-be-transcendental-is-there-a-survey-about-up-to) for the (not at all obvious) fact that it is transcendental.

Comment: But it is **not** a Liouville number.  The error in the $n$'th partial sum is on the order of $e_n \sim 2^{-(n+1)^2}$ while the denominator of that partial sum is $d_n = 2^{n^2}$.  Since $e_n$ is much bigger than $1/d_n^2$, it's not Liouville, nor can you use Thue-Siegel-Roth.

Comment: Can someone explain the first step,how choosing q to be less than 2^n makes the sum go from k+1 up to infinity?

Comment: There must be a typo in the first equality, as the LHS is deemed to be $0$. The sum should be to $n$.

Comment: It seems that typo is continued in several different places.  For example, the sentence "we know that the sum $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{k^2}} = \frac{m}{2^{n^2}}$" does not make any sense unless we change to $\sum_{k=1}^n$.

Comment: As can be seen here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2218878/confusion-over-summation another user is confused by these errors. Is it considered rude if I edit this post to remove these errors?

Comment: I am sorry. I just noticed the typo. In order to get an answer out quicker, I have copy-pasted the sum from the question. This has resulted in repeated typos due to copy-pasting :( I will correct the typos. Thank you for pointing them out. Sorry again for all the confusion caused.

Comment: Thanks! Now you only need to change the $b$ in $\frac1{2^{n^2}b}$ into $q$ and that last of the errors I noticed will be gone.

Comment: Done. Sorry about it again, will be less careless in the future.

Comment: No need to apologize. Thanks again for the edit!

Comment: @Rajiv Kaipa thank for the edit. I have one clarification. How does one obtain the inequality, p/q - m/(2^n^2) > 1/(2^n^2)? Maybe I'm unable to see something very obvious. Also in 'we know that the sum..' shouldn't it be for some integer m rather than n?

Comment: We have $2^{n^2}p - mq > 1$ (due to our choice of $q < 2^n$

Comment: @RobertIsrael Glah - I did the arithmetic (on the Liouville test) completely wrong.  Mea culpa.

Answer (score 8):

A real number is rational if and only if its positional representation (in any base) either terminates, or repeats. (To see this, perform long division of a rational $a/b$ in a given base, and notice that the calculation at step $i$ depends only on the remainder at step $i-1$. For the converse, you can compute the rational number directly by noting that the positional representation is a geometric series.)

Now your series converges to a number which, when written in binary, clearly does not repeat, so is irrational.

Answer (score 0):

No, if it were it would have ultimately periodic exapnsion for every base $b$. Now in binary we have the binary expansion being $1$ at position $n^2$ and $0$ otherwise. This is clearly not periodic.