# Confusion over summation

Tags: real-analysis

Before Someone marks this duplicate, this is from an answer just given in this site for another question. But I'm unable to follow this step, how choosing $q<2^n$ forces summation to go on from $k \geq n+1$?

[image]

Comment: what was the original sum?

Comment: It is the sum which is subtracted from p/q. It was regarding proving that the sum is irrational.

Comment: @DanielEvans Without the context of the problem we are left just as in the dark over the summation as you are. Can you please send us a link to the original problem or the name of it?

Comment: I'm adding the link http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2218794/is-the-number-sum-limits-n-1-infty2-n2-rational

Comment: I would assume a typo, $\infty$ to be replaced by $n$. Otherwise the LHS is simply $0$.

Comment: In that solution are a few 'clerical' problems that will probably confuse you. First, all the time the solution has a sum that ends in $\infty$, it actually ends in $n$. This is not only true in the place you have marked, but also the next 2 times it comes up. Second, near the end a variable $b$ turns up that should be a $q$.

Comment: Sum ends in n in the sense that it is not up to inifinity? But if it's a finite sum how can we prove that the infinite sum is irrational?

Comment: I'm talking about the *solution*, not the problem. Just replace any of the 3 instances where the $\infty$-symbol comes up in the solution with $n$, and the one instance where $b$ comes up with $q$, then you get something that's correct. I'm not saying that the solution does not contain infinite sums, the sum $\sum_{k \ge n+1}\frac1{2^{k^2}}$ from above certainly is infinite.

Comment: I am the poster of the solution. I apologise for the typos I have made due to careless copy-pasting of the text commands from the question. I have corrected them. Sorry for the confusion caused.